# How to eliminate black lag area in Java Swing running on Windows

Tags: java, swing

There is a common issue on every Swing application I wrote: black area appears when resizing window, even for the simplest code below:

```java
import javax.swing.*;

public class SampleWindow extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SampleWindow sampleWindow = new SampleWindow();
        sampleWindow.setTitle("Sample Window");

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.add(new JLabel(
                System.getProperty("os.name") + " Java " + System.getProperty("java.version")
        ), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        sampleWindow.setContentPane(contentPane);
        sampleWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        sampleWindow.setSize(400, 200);
        sampleWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

And let's see what JavaFX acts:

[image]

Is there any way to eliminate this?

---

I'm tring to add a component listener and print when event comes:

```java
sampleWindow.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Resizing event: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
});
```

I got these output:

```
Resizing event: 1614328759426
Resizing event: 1614328759524    // huge delay
Resizing event: 1614328759525
Resizing event: 1614328759525
Resizing event: 1614328759525
Resizing event: 1614328759525
Resizing event: 1614328759525
Resizing event: 1614328759526
Resizing event: 1614328759526
```

It is obvious that there is a huge delay between first line and second line. I think trying to handle resizing event is no effort.

---

I've found even IntelliJ also has a similar issue, so alright I give up :(

[image]

Comment: @Abra Java version is irrelevant, I updated the question.

Comment: @matt I updated the question, and it didn't work.

Comment: One more thing to try, not really a practical solution, but it might let you check. Set a swing timer that requests a repaint frequently. Maybe even 1ms frequency. Otherwise there are some command line arguments to affect how swing does the painting.

Comment: 1) Why are thosr black areas a problem? 2) Maybe, if all else fails, you could cheat using translucent Windows? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html

Comment: @JayC667 1) No other UI framework acts like this, even JavaFX. 2) Any workaround without a standard window decorator would bring other problems such as edge docking,

Comment: @Abra this question is specially for Swing and I am fully aware that there are other UI frameworks which work quite nicely.

Comment: I don't see this effect on 2 different machines of mine, maybe this is related to your hardware.

Comment: I have 2 different machines. The older one having Intel i5 6th Gen shows this issue even with any window. Rather the newer one having Intel i5 10th Gen doesn't show anything like this. So I agree with @dpr on this

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do the animation, but I didn't experience the black area with this code.

[image: Sample Window GUI]

My takeaway is to always start your Swing application with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Here's the code I ran.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SampleWindow implements Runnable {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SampleWindow());
    }
    
    private String properties;
    
    public SampleWindow() {
        this.properties = System.getProperty("os.name") + " Java " + 
                System.getProperty("java.version");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame sampleWindow = new JFrame();
        sampleWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        sampleWindow.setTitle("Sample Window");
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel(properties);
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        sampleWindow.add(contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        sampleWindow.setSize(400, 200);
        sampleWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I will check your solution ASAP, thanks, and besides, I am using [ShareX](https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX) to take screen recordings. That is an amazing tool!

Comment: If you drag the mouse quickly and far, you may see a small black area for a split second. That's what I experienced.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. ![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EVQc.gif)